# Why did dogs become extinct in the future, whereas cats did not?

Tags: futurama

Why exactly did dogs become extinct in the future, whereas cats did not?

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim that dogs are extinct in the future? I can't remember this being explicitly stated.

Comment: @gnovice Paleontologist looked at fossilized dog (Seymor)

Comment: @Blue: Fossilized specimen != extinct species

Comment: @gnovice True, however why would you need to inspect a specimen if there were species of that specimen still alive? **Paleontologist**

Comment: @Blue: As the paleontologist says to Fry in the episode "Jurassic Bark", they want to learn about dogs "from your time", which may be slightly different than dogs 1000 years later.

Comment: Cats will never be extinct because the Futurama/Simpsons people love drawing cat-ladies!

Comment: Also, cats are in fact a highly intelligent (although incredibly lazy) aliens.

Answer (score 10):

They aren't extinct. You can clearly see Dogs in the pet show in the episode "The day the earth stood stupid".

Sadly, I can't find any screen shots, but [this site](http://smotri.com/video/view/?id=v1046583ab4b) has the episode you can watch for yourself.

Comment: But I seem to recollect that in Jurassic Bark, someone (maybe Hermes or the Professor) mentions that dogs have been extinct for a long while, and on another episode, I remember seeing another fossilized Dachshund, that Hermes promptly gets rids of by saying, "Another of Fry's dogs!"

Comment: @AdityaSimha The Infosphere has [full episode transcripts](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Jurassic_Bark), so if you can find a quote, you should edit it into your question.

Comment: Hmm...interesting, I don't see the quote on here. I don't know why, but I really did think I remember hearing someone saying that dogs were extinct......

Answer (score 10):

I think you may be confusing poodles (a breed of dog) with all dogs;

> **Farnsworth:** *Pine trees have been extinct for 800 years, Fry. Gone the way of the poodle and your primitive notions of modesty. Ah!
> Brisk!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Futurama: Xmas Story](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Xmas_Story)</sup></sub>

As has been noted in the other answers, dogs of other breeds do appear in later episodes.

[image]
**<sub><sup>[Futurama: The Day the Earth Stood Stupid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeQZVEadKFE)</sup></sub>**

[image]
**<sub><sup>[Bender's Game](https://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Game)</sup></sub>**